# Sum Two Columns in Two Mysql Tables

Tags: mysql

I've been searching everywhere for this but no cigar. Smoke is starting to come out of my ears. please help

How do you sum two columns in two tables and group by userid?

Have two tables.

```
Recipe Table
recipeid   userid   recipe_num_views

Meals Table
mealsid   userid    meal_num_views
```

Goal is to sum the num views in both tables and group by userid

```
so for example
Recipe Table
1    3     4
2    4     6

Meal Table
1    3     2
2    4     5


select sum(recipe views)+sum(meal views) 
WHERE recipe.userid=meals.userid GROUP BY userid
```

should give

```
userid=3 , sum=6
userid=4, sum=11
```

this gives a much bigger number.

Comment: Smoke with no cigar, that's bad.

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT recipe.userid, sum(recipe_num_views+meal_num_views) 
FROM Recipe JOIN Meals ON recipe.userid=meals.userid
GROUP BY recipe.userid
```

#### EDIT:

OK, from your comments, I understand that when you have for **user 3**: *4 recipes* & *3 meals* you will get the sum of the combination of all these rows => ***`sum(recipes)*3 + sum(meals)*4`***

Try this query instead:

```
select r.userid, (sum_recipe + sum_meal) sum_all
FROM
(select userid, sum(recipe_num_views) sum_recipe
FROM Recipe
GROUP BY userid) r
JOIN (
select userid, sum(meal_num_views) sum_meal
FROM Meals
GROUP BY userid) m ON r.userid = m.userid
```

Comment: somethign like 6 million instead of 100,000

Comment: Can you answer the following questions: How many Recipes for userid=1? How many Meals for userid=1? What do you get with this query for userid=1? (userid=1 is an example, you can choose what you want, but it should be the same for the 3 of them)

Comment: ok here it is:SELECT sum(num_views) FROM `recipes` WHEre userid=3
gives 99316

BUT 
SELECT sum(recipes.num_views) FROM `recipes`,`meals` WHEre recipes.userid=3 AND recipes.userid=meals.userid
gives
2979480

Comment: also tried this:SELECT sum(recipes.num_views) FROM `recipes` JOIN meals on recipes.userid=meals.userid WHERE recipes.userid=3 GROUP BY recipes.userid    this also gives 2979480

Comment: @user813801, i think, you should check your database (look at result set without group by and sum), 'cause queries in both answers are right ans should return correct sum.

Comment: OK, from your comments I undertand that when you have for user 3: 4 recipes & 3 meals you will get the sum of the combination of all these rows => sum(recipes)*3 + sum(meals)*4. See my edit. _(I guess you have 30 rows (2979480/99316) in Meals table for userid=3)_

Comment: thanks alot Manji. will try it out. looks like i opened a can of worms with this seemingly simple problem

Comment: I tried it. Very close but no cigar. I tried to check it manually by getting sum of recipes individually for userid=3 then sum of meals individually for userid=3. This gives:116913  your query gives 116912 (one less for userid=3).

Comment: Weird...can ou test for another user? (you table was not updated (meal or recipe got inserted) while you were testing?)

Answer (score 2):

If you're selecting from 2 tables you need to join them.
Otherwise MySQL will not know how to link up the two tables.

```
select sum(recipe_num_views + meal_num_views) 
from recipe r
inner join meals m ON (r.user_id = m.user_id)
group by m.user_id
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html