# Sum of the columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have situation like this:

```
- name    value
-------------
- stuff_1  2
- stuff2   5
- stuff2   3
- stuff_1  4
```

---

Which mysql query do I have to use in order to sum all these values and to get something like this:

```
- name    value
-------------
- stuff_1  2+4=6
- stuff2   5+3=8
```

Comment: Dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465949/sum-two-columns-in-two-mysql-tables

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
select name, sum(value) from table_name group by name
```

Take a look at MySQL [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and aggregation functions listed there

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT name, SUM(value) FROM your_table GROUP BY name;
```