# Issue with SUM function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.lineId), A.title, A.label, A.price * OD.quantity FROM Additional A JOIN OrderDetail OD ON A.orderId=OD.orderId WHERE A.orderId=179 ORDER BY A.lineId
```

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/839/kfzq.png

Everything is ok at this point, but If I use SUM function over `A.price * OD.quantity`, It should give me "176" as result and is not it. Look:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/802/kh4f.png

Why it is happening?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause if you want to SUM something. Im not sure what you want to sum up at the moment...

Comment: I would be tempted to give "A.price * OD.quantity" an alias "A.price * OD.quantity AS PQ" to avoid improve semantics as initially the asterisks reads as a multiplication, im not sure if mysql is interpreting it as that? Seems like Linoff knows more...

Comment: If you quit the `Distinct` the data returned sums 352?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.lineId), A.title, A.label, A.price * OD.quantity
FROM Additional A JOIN
     OrderDetail OD
     ON A.orderId=OD.orderId
WHERE A.orderId=179
ORDER BY A.lineId;
```

The first line is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.lineId, A.title, A.label, A.price * OD.quantity
```

So, it returns a row when all four values are distinct.  The parentheses mean nothing.  *HOWEVER*, you may have duplicate lines that are missing.  You probably get different results when you do:

```
SELECT A.lineId, A.title, A.label, A.price * OD.quantity
```

*This* is the data that the sum is using.  If you want a `sum` on the distinct values, use a subquery:

```
SELECT LineId, Title, Label, sum(pg)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.lineId, A.title, A.label, A.price * OD.quantity as pq
      FROM Additional A JOIN
           OrderDetail OD
           ON A.orderId=OD.orderId
      WHERE A.orderId=179
     ) t;
```

Usually, the need for such a query suggests that something is quite wrong with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to multiply them instead of add.  Check this out, see if it helps at all [Sum Two Columns in Two Mysql Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465949/sum-two-columns-in-two-mysql-tables)